# Mostrar total de mensajes por sesiones de usuarios

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema con una consulta. Quiero mostrar el total de mensajes que se le ha enviado a cada usuario.

Ejemplo: Carlos tiene 2 mensajes y Juan tiene 1 mensaje pero cuando entro en la sesión de Carlos me aparece 3 mensajes. Osea, me lo está contando en el total de los mensajes y no por la sesión de ese usuario.

NOTA: sé que este código está obsoleto, pero son trozos de sistemas que estoy terminando para luego migrar a PDO.

Anexo el código:

```
<!-- proceso para consultar-->
<?php
$login= $_SESSION['login'];
$password=$_SESSION['password'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login='$login' AND 
password='$password'";
$resultl=mysql_query($sql,$link);//devuelve la consulta
$_editar_linea=mysql_fetch_array($resultl);{
?>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mjs INNER JOIN usuario ON mjs.fk_cedula=usuario.id 
WHERE idnivel_usuario='Empleado' AND estado_mjs='No leido'";
$resultl=mysql_query($sql,$link)or die("Error en: $busqueda: " . 
mysql_error());
$campo=mysql_fetch_array($resultl);
$totalmjs=mysql_num_rows($resultl);
{
?>
 <li><a href="mjs.php">Mjs <span class="new badge blue"><?=$totalmjs?>
</span></a></li>
<?php
}
?>
<?php
}
?>
<!--fin proceso para consultar-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que estás sufriendo es que estás contando TODOS los registros en la tabla `mjs` que cumplan la condición `idnivel_usuario='Empleado' AND estado_mjs='No leido'` y no estás teniendo en cuenta que el destinatario sea el usuario en cuestión.

Personalmente no te recomiendo almacenar en las variables de sesión el usuario y contraseña del usuario, es información sensible que podría ser robada del servidor. Deberías guardar información útil sobre el usuario al que pertenece la sesión, por ejemplo su identificador de usuario, `usuario.id`, con lo que te ahorras:

1. Comprobar en cada acceso a un PHP la comprobación de usuario y contraseña.
2. Consultar la tabla de usuarios para obtener el identificador de usuario para acceder a sus datos de otras tablas relacionadas.

Dejando de lado esos temas (si quieres me lo puedes pedir y te podría hacer un ejemplo de cómo se haría correctamente) te expongo el código que funciona correctamente y una breve explicación:

```
<!-- proceso para consultar-->
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario.id'])) {
  $login = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['login']);
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['password']);
  $sql = "SELECT id FROM usuario WHERE login='$login' AND 
password='$password'";
  $resultl = mysql_query($sql,$link);//devuelve la consulta
  if ($resultl === false) {
    die(mysql_error());
  }
  $_editar_linea = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultl);
  if ($_editar_linea === false) {
    die('Acceso denegado');
  }
  $_SESSION['usuario.id'] = $_editar_linea['id'];
}
$id_usuario = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['usuario.id']);
$sql = "
  SELECT
    COUNT(*) numero
  FROM
    mjs
  WHERE
    idnivel_usuario = 'Empleado'
  AND
    estado_mjs = 'No leido'
  AND
    fk_cedula = '$id_usuario'
";
$resultl = mysql_query($sql,$link) or die("Error en: $sql: " . 
mysql_error());
$campo = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultl);
?>
 <li><a href="mjs.php">Mjs <span class="new badge blue"><?= htmlspecialchars($campo['numero']) ?>
</span></a></li>
<!--fin proceso para consultar-->
```

Para empezar, debes escapar las cadenas de caracteres correctamente antes de introducirlas en una consulta SQL. Ya que no tienes a tu disposición consultas preparadas con asociación de variables (como ofrece PDO o mysqli) entonces debes hacer uso de la función [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string).

Si no lo haces podrías sufrir ataques de inyección SQL que expusieran información sensible de tu empresa. Para empezar, como no usas algoritmos de `hash` para almacenar las contraseñas en tu base de datos, podrían acceder a los usuarios y contraseñas en texto plano.

He creado un bloque de control inicial para ahorrar la consulta a la base de datos para obtener el `usuario.id`. Sólo se obtendrá la primera vez, las siguientes visitas se reutilizará el valor almacenado en las variables de sesión.

La consulta `SELECT COUNT(*) numero` obtendrá el número de registros sin tener que sobrecargar al servidor MySQL enviando todos y cada uno de los mensajes al script PHP (y también ahorrando memoria en ambos extremos) con un alias `numero` para ser accedido desde el resultado.

En algunos lados de tu código abres bloques de código `{ ... }` sin asociar a ninguna instrucción de control que no son necesarios y, por lo tanto, los he eliminado de mi respuesta.

Por último, aunque sé que es un número, te recomiendo que uses [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) siempre que vayas a mostrar en el documento información obtenida de la base de datos para evitar ataques de inyección HTML, CSS y/o JS.

Comment: oye OscarGarcia buena respuesta gracias ahora tengo una duda

Comment: De nada, un placer. Por cierto, no soy adivino :) ¿me cuentas la duda? Si abres una nueva pregunta déjame el enlace aquí en un comentario.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66960/problemas-con-una-conulta

Answer (score 0):

ya lo he resuelto amigos queda de la siguiente forma

```
    <!-- proceso para consultar-->
    <?php
    $login= $_SESSION['login'];
    $password=$_SESSION['password'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mjs, usuario  WHERE usuario.login='$login' AND 
usuario.password='$password' AND 
usuario.idnivel_usuario='Empleado' AND mjs.estado_mjs='No leido' AND 
mjs.fk_cedula=usuario.id";
$resultl=mysql_query($sql,$link)or die("Error en: $busqueda: " . 
mysql_error());
$campo=mysql_fetch_array($resultl);
$totalmjs=mysql_num_rows($resultl);
{
?>
<li><a href="mjs.php">Mjs <span class="new badge blue"><?=$totalmjs?></span>
</a></li>
<?php
}
?>
<!--fin proceso para consultar-->
```

doy por cerrado el tema

Comment: Me alegra que solucionaras tu problema. Pero para que sea una buena respuesta, responde como si no fueras tambien el que pregunta. Explica qué habia mal en la pregunta y como tu respuesta lo soluciona. Pegar codigo solamente no es recomendable. En 48h podrás aceptar tu respuesta. Un saludo